# Replace all spaces with "-"

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I want to replace all spaces with `-` and just remove space if the line contains `-` using sed in bash, for example

`asd asd` -> `asd-asd`
`asd - asd` -> `asd-asd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match spaces and dashes and replace by a single dash:

```
s/[ -]\+/-/g
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tr` with the `-s` option ("squeeze"):

```
$ tr -s ' ' - <<< 'asd asd'
asd-asd
$ tr -s ' ' - <<< 'asd - asd'
asd-asd
```

Answer (score 0):

I might use two sed lines:

```
$ sed '{
  s/ *- */-/g;
  s/ \+/-/g;
 }' input_file_name > output_file_name
```

The first line converts all dashes surrounded by spaces to just dashes.  The second line now replaces any string of spaces to a single dash.

For in place modification, use `-i`:

```
$ sed -i '{
  s/ *- */-/g;
  s/ \+/-/g;
 }' input_file_name
```

This can be reduced to a single line if the formatting is an issue:

```
$ sed -i '{ s/ *- */-/g; s/ \+/-/g; }' input_file_name
```